Pair of lines joining origin to points of intersection of $y=2-x^2$ and $y^2=9x$
The parabolas
$y=2-x^2$ and $y^2=9x\cdots (*)$
can be checked to intersect at $P[\frac{3}{2}(3-\sqrt{5}), -\frac{3}{2}(1-\sqrt{5}]$ and $Q[\frac{3}{2}(3+\sqrt{5}),-\frac{3}{2}(1+\sqrt{5}]$ the Eqs. of OP and OQ are $y=\frac{3}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})x$ and $y=\frac{3}{2}(1-\sqrt{5})x.$
So the combined eq. of OP and OQ is
$y^2-3xy-9x^2=0\cdots (**)$
The question is: Can we get (**) by homogenization method of eqs. (*)?

idk...but if you perform the change of axis as $2-y=Y$ then the other parabola i.e. $y^2=x$ will get disturbed

Let's homogenize by $z,$ resulting in four points in ${\Bbb P}^2_{\Bbb C}$ or four lines through the origin in $3$-space.
Noticing $(3x-y+6z)(3x+y-3z)-9(x^2-2z^2+yz)+(y^2-9xz)$, your two are the real $\langle 3x+y-3z,x^2-2z^2+yz,y^2-9xz\rangle=\langle 3z-3x-y, 9x^2+3xy-y^2\rangle,$ the other factor resulting in complex conjugate solutions. A phrase to search for is primary decomposition (over ${\Bbb Q}).$
In the usual affine plane, dehomogenizing again by setting $z=1$ this means $\langle 3-3x-y, 9x^2+3xy-y^2\rangle.$ The interpretation of which is that the two real intersection points are on the line $y=3-3x$ and the line pair $9x^2+3xy-y^2=0$ through the origin.
